# Transparent jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

anybody knows how to make the ui dialog transparent ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create a class:

```
   .transparent_class {
        filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* for IE4 - IE7 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE8 */
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
   }
```

and add this class to your UI element.

Read more about MS IE filters on [their blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx)

Comment: this will make the UI element and it's content transparent

Comment: I don't know IE that good (and don't like it) but it seems as it needs a value like `filter: alpha(opacity = 50);`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. didn't see that I had it in the class already. From IE8 on you need an additional `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";`. But I can not try it out now. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a style like the following and use the dialogClass option on those dialogs you want to have a transparent background. Of course you can make multiple styles and pass in whatever you want

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .transparent { background:transparent }
</style>

//make dialog with transparent background
$("#dialog").dialog({dialogClass:'transparent'});
//make default dialog
$("#dialog2").dialog();
```

Check demo site: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ifoja) (basic jquery, jquery ui, jquery ui css + custom css transparent class)