# jquery modal / dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to  use some jquery plugin to show modal. I have been using fancybox but it has problem that second fancybox can not be shown on one. I have used jquery UI but it has images and I want some plugin which is not dependent on images. Here are my requirements:

1. to show on page load
2. to show on ajax success
3. customizable with custom css
4. second modal/dialog can be shown on first one.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I like `http://jqueryui.com/dialog/`      I know you said that you used it but did not like it as it has images,  but I would override your images with custom css - which is not to difficult. simnple model is fine but I find ui better

Comment: Can I use my custom css with jquery ui dialog without using jquery ui themeroller.

Comment: You don't need the theme roller just use fire bug to find the images in the dialogue and remove them in custom css in the head of the page.Its a bit of a hack but at least you can custimise with out messing with the library

Comment: Here is an example to make the background of the box transparent  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623817/transparrent-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: Can I make it look like fancybox with X for closing at top and shadow ?

Comment: you can do anything its just CSS at the end of the day that overrides the ui defaults once you get you head around the first css overide then its easy. how good is your css?

Comment: .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    top: -20px;
}

Comment: and do jquery ui dialog js uses elements by name like if i dont have ui-dialog-titlebar-close in my css then script will work ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23624/discussion-between-dotnetsparrow-and-hello-world)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not in the Q&A format of Stackoverflow, because you are essentially soliciting opinions (i.e., no definitive answer).

Nevertheless, [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) is an excellent light-weight jQuery plugin I've used for modal dialog boxes.

Comment: Can I use my css with simpleModal ? is it better than fancybox and colorbox in my requirements

Comment: The CSS is completely customizable with your own external specifications. Please see the section entitled 'Styling' on http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Thanks @Elliot: Can I use second SimpleModal on one ?

Comment: You can re-use it as many times as you'd like on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this one, I used it in the past: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery